# One liner for comparing by property and returning a stream?

Tags: java

Is it possible to sort and return a stream in one line as in the following?

```
//@Getter...
public List<Actor> actors;

public Stream<Actor> actors() {
    //can these two lines be combined somehow?
    actors.sort(Comparator.comparing(Actor::getName));
    return actors.stream();
}
```

**Note:** After posting this question, I gather this would lead to a design that is not ideal and perhaps error-prone, as it would mutate state outside of the method.  Thanks to @knittl for pointing this out.

Comment: You could sort the stream, but it wouldn't give you the exact same results, as your current method leaves `actors` sorted.

Comment: It's way clearer in two lines anyway IMHO. You're mutating in one line, it would be weird to mix it with something immutable.

Comment: Not a solution to your question, but I'd reconsider changing the object's state inside of a getter method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really, really must:

```java
public Stream<Actor> actors() {
    return (actors = actors.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Actor::getName))
        .toList()).stream();
}
```

Because it is possible, doesn't mean you should do this.

---

But indeed, knittl is right. You shouldn't mutate `actors` with this getter method. I'd be really surprised if I were to use this method and suddenly `actors` was sorted.

There are some options which are better alternatives to your current design:

- Sort the resulting stream, but don't mutate `actors`:

  ```java
  return actors.stream()
      .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Actor::getName));
  ```
- Sort `actors` on initialization, for example:

  ```java
  List<Actor> actors;

  YourConstructor(List<Actor> actors) {
      this.actors = actors.stream()
          .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Actor::getName))
          .toList(); // Or whatever implementation of List is desired
  }
  ```

Comment: If the side effect is intentional, OP's approach is much better.

Comment: @shmosel Of course it is! But OP asked for a one-liner.

Comment: Also not entirely equivalent if there are other references to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Streams has a [sorted method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-)

```
actors.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Actor::getName))
```

Note: This will not sort the List. And will only sort the returned stream.

Comment: I guess the OP want to keep the list sorted after the operation, so it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Tudny that's correct

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
return actors.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Actor::getName));
```

The sort Method of a List will return void, so there is no chance to concat.

Greetings

Comment: Sorry, how is this different from @Worive's answer?

Comment: @vphilipnyc Well, this answer was posted 23 seconds later – a very short interval.

Comment: Ok, my status wouldn't show me that interval.  It used to just read something like "2 days ago" without a way to mouseover